# How to select values in an sql table using columnname

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
CODE   bra1   bra2   bra3   bra4   bra5
---------------------------------------
 a1      0      1      1      2      1
 a2      1      0      0      0      0 
 a3      0      1      0      0      0
 a4      2      0      2      1      0
```

How can I display the rows with value `CODE='a1'` and column name='bra1'

Here the CODE, bra1, bra2 etc are my columns

Comment: `select bra1 from yourTable where CODE = 'a1'` or something? Can you please be more clear about your question?

Comment: Sir I need to display the item having CODE 'a1' and total items in the bra1

Comment: did you try anything? this is too basic.

Comment: Can you write down the expected result of the query based on the example in your question?  You can edit the question to add this info.

Comment: `SELECT (columns) FROM (yourtable) WHERE code = 'a1'` ??? Not clear - every row has a column `bra1` - what do you mean by *and column name = 'bra1'* ??

Comment: Sir, sorry for the incomplete question. I have a table in sql in which contain field or column name code and bra1,bra2,bra3 etc. In my asp.net application I need to display the result. I have two texboxes. In my textbox I will type the code number 'a1' and textbox two my Fieldname 'bra1'. So I need to get the result. I need to specify the field name. I have written the code.but its wrong.I need to specify the column name or field name value bra1. here I have put my code

Comment: String str = " Select @search1 From table Where code='@search';";
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "BranchCode");
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();

Answer (score 2):

> Sir I need to display the item having CODE 'a1' and total items in the
>   bra1

Based on that, you can use [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) with filtering your query with `CODE = 'a1'` like;

```
Select SUM(bra1) as bra1Count
From tableName
Where CODE = 'a1'
```

<kbd>[`SQLFIDDLE DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d18fb/3)</kbd>

```
| bra1Count |
|-----------|
|         0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display the rows

then => `Select`

> having value CODE='a1'

then => `Where code='a1'`

> and column name='bra1'

then => `Select bra1`

so the whole thing is:

```
Select bra1
From yourtablename
Where code='a1'
```